# Android studio build error

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Tried to create my first project in android studio, using one of the examples im trying to run the application, but gradle gives me this build error (didnt change one line of code - just trying to run the Empty activity):

> Gradle:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Passivelocation:packageDebug'.
>
> > org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer.(J)V
> >     * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Ive tried adding info and debug while running the command on with the cli but i cant make much of the output it gives me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions? Yes ! post the output you have when running from command line with --info or --debug or --stacktrace option

Comment: Sorry about that @ben75 - Ive uploaded them to gist [--debug](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5777335) and [--info](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5777355) and [--stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5777365) and [all combined](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5777376)

Comment: It seems to be an issue when adding the signature in the apk. Are you using the latest SDK tools (rev 22 I think) ? Wich version of the android-gradle-plugin are you using (I think the latest is 0.4.1 or 0.4.2) ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same failure and the problem was with my jdk/jre because some time ago I added the Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs functionality by adding the jar to my jdk/jre path.
I tried a `gradle build` with a "clean" jdk/jre and problem was solved